# What would be the best way to extract the year from this set of inconsitently formated dates?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large data set in excel containing lots of info about steam games. I would like to be able to extract the release date of each game and then use it with another data set that I have. Unfortunately the release dates vary wildly in formatting

eg. 
`Nov 15 2016`,`Early 2017`,`Coming Soon`,`1/01/2017`,`Coming 2017`.

I would like to be able to just get the year from each of these cells eg. `2017` or return false if no date is detected. what could I do? I am using office 365 excel.

[Link to the data set for reference](https://data.world/craigkelly/steam-game-data)

Comment: You would need to search for 4 numeric characters. And while I'm sure someone could write a very clever  but unreadable Excel function that does exactly that, your best bet may be to write some VBA code that uses a regular expression. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops . Of course, if the text is 'Coming soon' all bets are off.

Comment: I found a link on that page, but you need to sign in to open it.  So it isn't helpful.  Please extract some sample data and embed it in your question.  That said, can we assume all entries are text?  What would you do with "coming soon"?

Comment: Split each cell into an array (by the spaces) and test each element to be a number, and in the range of, for example, 1900-3000.  Then return the largest number.  You should first test to see if the `YEAR` function returns a valid year, or an error as it would in your 4th example.

Comment: Oh, and what version of Excel do you have?  If you have Excel 2013+, the converting to array and testing can be done fairly simply.

Answer (score 1):

**With the help of UDF(User Defined Function) & Formula, your problem can be fixed:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- **Right Click** on *Sheet Tab* & from Poped up 
  Menu Click **View Code**.
- **Copy & Paste** this Code as **Module**.

  ```
  Function RetNum(Str As String)

  Dim xRegEx As Object
  Set xRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  xRegEx.Global = True
  xRegEx.Pattern = "[^\d]+"
  RetNum = xRegEx.Replace(Str, "")
  Set xRegEx = Nothing

  End Function
  ```
- In VB Editor Windows Click **Tools** then 
  **References** and ensure that **Microsoft 
  Scripting Runtime** DLL has been included.

[image]

- Return to the Sheet.
- Enter this Formula & fill it down.

`=IF(ISTEXT(A1),RetNum(A1),YEAR(A1))`

*Adjust cell references as your need.*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the range of years is from 1980 to 2030, and all years are in 4 characters, and the test text is in A1. A mid() + recursive iferror() with find() will do just fine.

Implementation :

```
=MID(A1,(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(FIND(1980,A1),FIND(1981,A1)),FIND(1982,A1)),FIND(1983,A1)),FIND(1984,A1)),FIND(1985,A1)),FIND(1986,A1)),FIND(1987,A1)),FIND(1988,A1)),FIND(1989,A1)),FIND(1990,A1)),FIND(1991,A1)),FIND(1992,A1)),FIND(1993,A1)),FIND(1994,A1)),FIND(1995,A1)),FIND(1996,A1)),FIND(1997,A1)),FIND(1998,A1)),FIND(1999,A1)),FIND(2000,A1)),FIND(2001,A1)),FIND(2002,A1)),FIND(2003,A1)),FIND(2004,A1)),FIND(2005,A1)),FIND(2006,A1)),FIND(2007,A1)),FIND(2008,A1)),FIND(2009,A1)),FIND(2010,A1)),FIND(2011,A1)),FIND(2012,A1)),FIND(2013,A1)),FIND(2014,A1)),FIND(2015,A1)),FIND(2016,A1)),FIND(2017,A1)),FIND(2018,A1)),FIND(2019,A1)),FIND(2020,A1)),FIND(2021,A1)),FIND(2022,A1)),FIND(2023,A1)),FIND(2024,A1)),FIND(2025,A1)),FIND(2026,A1)),FIND(2027,A1)),FIND(2028,A1)),FIND(2029,A1)),FIND(2030,A1))),4)
```

p/s : this formula produces a string. You may use `numbervalue()` to convert it to number if needed.

Hope it helps.